# Hyperledger composer & couch DB

Tags: docker, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I have developed a hyperledger composer application with a number of  queries and transactions. I would like to find a way to expose the docker  container and interface to it with fauxton.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the docker-compose.yml file and under couchdb heading add

```
  image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
  ports:
    - 6984:5984
```

open your browser http://localhost:6984/_utils/ would take you to fauxton remember to up the network with this yml file